# Android call a particular method when phone switched between foreground and background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am developing an Android app, in which I have to call a particular web service, when user switches my app to background and vice versa.

When user moves my app to background, I have to call a particular method (web service) and when user switches my app to foreground, a method should be called.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read and understand about the [Android Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and you will be rewarded with an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried with the onPause(), onStop(), onStart() and onResume() methods. But the issue with these are, consider that, my app is in foreground, and when I lock the phone, the onPause() method is called (as the app is not visible). For me, I need some action to be called when my app or activity is in foreground and another method for background action. Suggestions please...

Comment: @Kamal Not sure whether I understand you. You mean, _your_ app should _not_ consider itself in the _background_ when the phone is _locked_, _although_ your app then _is_ in the background? Are there other exceptions where you want your app to consider itself in the foreground although Android considers it to be in the background?

Comment: Thanks for the response Class Stacker. Consider that my app is switched to foreground from background. During this, OnResume() will be called and I am using this to track my work. Now my app is actually in foreground. I lock my phone. During this time, onPause() is called. Actually, I need some method, which tracks my app, only when it is in foreground and background. (But not when the app is in foreground + during phone lock). Sorry if I am still confusing you. Suggestions please

Comment: So does it really _hurt_ to _track your work_ when the phone is locked? Because, depending on the Android version, your activity is considered to be killable by Android after onPause().

Comment: Yes. Because, my customer's requirement is, they have to log an entry (make a web service call), only when the app is in foreground and second entry when the app is changed to background..

Comment: Well, your app _is_ in the background when the phone is locked. Does your customer _really_ have a different definition of _background_ than Android?

Comment: I am new to android. So apologize if my question is wrong or simple. My customer requirement is, for every background and foreground action, I have to make a web service call and track the phone status. So what you are trying to say is, even phone lock is considered as the app background and phone unlock = app is in foreground. Am I right? Sorry again if my question seems to be simple

Comment: All Android docs say essentially that: Your app is either killed or in the background if it's not in the foreground. ;) Foreground is more or less defined as being visible to the user. That's not the case while the lock screen is being displayed. Your app is considered killable if the lock scrren is shown. Your app runs on a lower scheduling priority when the lock screen is shown. All that is because Android considers it to be in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Override the **onPause**() and **onResume**() methods of the **Activity** and implement your calls there.

- onPause() is called when the app goes to background (not visible).
- onResume() is called when the app goes to foreground

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried with the onPause() and onResume() methods. But the issue with these are, consider that, my app is in foreground, and when I lock the phone, the onPause() method is called (as the app is not visible). For me, I need some action to be called when my app or activity is in foreground and another method for background action. Suggestions please...